# Braintree API in PHP success and currency issue

Tags: php, braintree

My braintree integration is going well - there's just two minor issues.

Firstly what is the option name to pass through and specify a currency code e.g.:

```
$options = [
    "amount" => "10.00"
    "creditCard" => [
            "number" => "",
            "cvv"    => "",
            "expirationMonth" => "",
            "expirationYear" => ""
        ],
    "currencyCode" => "AUD" // This is what im after?
];
```

Secondly, when I run the code below I get this: "**Undefined property: Braintree_Result_Successful::$_attributes**" when running the check on success?

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale($this->collect_data());

if($result->success) { // do something }
```

Answer (score 3):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, please feel free to get in touch with [our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

To use a different currency, you [specify a different merchant account](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/transactions/create#specifying_merchant_account):

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
  'amount' => '100.00',
  'merchantAccountId' => 'gbp_merchant_account',
  'creditCard' => array(
    'number' => '5105105105105100',
    'expirationDate' => '05/12'
  )
));
```

Contact Braintree to get the additional merchant accounts set up.

For your second question, I've not seen that error before. Your best bet is to contact Braintree support so they can help you with the problem.

Comment: looks like I cannot add another merchant account in the production mode, any idea why is that?

Comment: @foxx I'm not sure what you mean. The request is the same in production as sandbox, though setting up the other merchant accounts may be different. I'd suggest you [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) if you're having problems. Keep in mind Thursday and Friday are company holidays for us so responses may be delayed.

Comment: What I mean is that while in sandbox, I have a button right above the merchant accounts table allowing me to add another merchant account with different currency, in production there is no such button, neither an explanation why is it removed or disabled..

Comment: @foxx If you search for "braintree currency" you should find [this article](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/currencies) which explains how multiple currencies work in production.